# What does "n-particle reducible" mean?

Tags: terminology, field-theory, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

I am reading Ramond and in page 112 he says "In $\lambda \phi^{4}$ theory, diagrams can be at most three-particle reducible". My question:

1. whether the individual Feynman Diagrams are treated as particles or not?
2. Are the dinosaur and sunset diagrams 2 and 3 particle reducible respectively?
3. What does [$n$-particle reducible](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=n+particle+reducible) mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A n-particle reducible diagram is a diagram that can be cut into two pieces if one cuts n or less lines. Conversely, a n-particle irreducible (n-PI) diagram cannot be cut into two pieces if one cuts n lines.

The sunset diagram is 3-particle reducible, since it has 3 internal lines, but it is both 1-PI and 2-PI, and contributes to the self-energy (which contains 1-PI diagrams) and when closed, to the Luttinger-Ward functional (that contains all vacuum 2-PI diagrams).

Comment: So the terminology has no relation whatsoever with treating Feynmann diagrams as particles ?

Comment: @AbhishekPal: Feynamn diagrams never represent particles. The particles here a the virtual particles represented by the lines in the diagram.